# how do i sort my character array in ascending order based on the same array with its int value?

Tags: c, sorting

Basically, a user will enter a unique id no. from 1 to 10 and a user name and he is allowed to do so in any order. What i have been trying to do is to link the unique id no. and username TOGETHER to print them out in ascending order but it manages to sort the id number but does not sort the usernames which is tagged to the id no.

**Input:**
What is your ID? : 3
What is your name? Lola

What is your ID? : 2
What is your name? Preston

What is your ID? : 1
What is your name? Killian

**Expected output:**
ID: 1
Your name: Killian

ID: 2
Your name: Preston

ID: 3
Your name: Lola

**Given output:**
ID: 1
Your name: Lola

ID: 2
Your name: Preston

ID: 3
Your name: Killian

```
void myGameDetails() {
    int temp, i, j, k, temp;
    
    if (counter > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < counter; ++j) {
            for (k = j + 1; k < counter; ++k) {
                if (userDetails[j].ID > userDetails[k].ID) {
                    temp = userDetails[j].ID;
                    userDetails[j].ID = userDetails[k].ID;
                    userDetails[k].ID = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
            printf("IDs in ascending order\n") 
            printf("ID: %d\n", userDetails[i].ID);
            printf("Your name: %s", userDetails[i].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] with hardcoded data for the two arrays, what you expect as output, and what you're currently seeing as output?

Comment: What is `counter`? The solution has to work for exactly three students?

Answer (score 1):

Code has the ID compare

```
if(userDetails[j].ID>userDetails[k].ID)
```

If the name is secondary to the ID in sorting criteria, then also test, when ID's are the same, by using `strcmp()` on the `.Name` members:

```
if(userDetails[j].ID > userDetails[k].ID ||
    (userDetails[j].ID == userDetails[k].ID && 
     strcmp(userDetails[j].Name, userDetails[k].Name) > 0)) {
```

If `.ID` is secondary, call `strcmp()` and save its result.

```
int scmp = strcmp(userDetails[j].Name, userDetails[k].Name);
if(scmp > 0  ||
    (scmp == 0 && userDetails[j].ID > userDetails[k].ID)) {
```